# Servlet's JSON output has SQL table column data in (undesirable) arbitrary order

Tags: java, mysql

My servlet is returning table column data in arbitrary order. I want it to return the column data in the order the columns are defined in the schema, or at least provide a means for the client to determine the correct order.

[image: MySQL Workbench screenshot of column default order]

Notice in the schema above, the column order is: ***person_id, firstname, lastname, fullname***

But the servlet is returning the JSON string with columns in a *different* order:

```
{"data":[{"LASTNAME":"Leonard","PERSON_ID":"0","FIRSTNAME":"Erick","FULLNAME":"Erick Leonard"}]}
```

Below are the DAO bean that issues the SQL command and the bean that retrieves the JSON.

**DAO Bean**

```
package com.queryData.dao;

import com.queryData.dbconnection.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DataDAO {
    DbConnection dbcon = new DbConnection();
    private static final String SQL = "select * from person";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        try {
            con = dbcon.setConnection();
            pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            resultSet = pst.executeQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Some Thing Went Wrong In getResultSet()");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

**Bean that retrieves the columns**

```
package com.queryData.services;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonServices {
    public static List<JSONObject> getFormattedResult(ResultSet rs) {
         List<JSONObject> resList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();        

        try {
            ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCnt = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCnt; i++) {

                // adding all retrieved column names to List object

                columnNames.add(rsMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase());
            }

            while (rs.next()) {

                // convert each object to an human readable JSON object

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCnt; i++) {
                    String key = columnNames.get(i - 1);
                    String value = rs.getString(i);
                    obj.put(key, value);
                }
                resList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the ORDER of the columns has no impact on the JSON string, I am only wondering if something I omitted in the code or included in the code causes such unnatural change with no apparent sequence of order, not numeric, nor alphabetic sequence of the four table column names.

Comment: Made question more succinct and formatted it to be easier to read, including putting problem introduction near the top, adding vertical space to the code, removing redundant/extraneous comments, and making the image show without having to click the link.